# PowerShell - Reading from CSV GBP(£) Sign

Tags: powershell

I'm having some trouble reading from a CSV file whereby GBP signs (£) are output as question marks.

I'm iterating through the CSV file using a ForEach

```
ForEach ($line in $csv) {
    Write-Host $line.message
}
```

A typical entry in the message column of the CSV might be:

"Please top up your rent balance with £50"  but when output it is "Please top up your rent balance with ?50".

I understand that this may be solved by escaping the sign but I've had no luck using replace or `ToString("c")`

Is anyone able to help or point me in the right direction?

Comment: What about encoding?  This reads like an encoding issue.  i could be wrong, however.  Or, instead of Write-Host just remove that and display `$line.message` with no write-host preceding it.

Comment: It still prints the same.  I'm using Import-Csv but when I change it to Get-Content, it works as expected...

Comment: I don't think PS can display that symbol. `[char]156` just prints an empty box. Why are you using [`Write-Host`](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/)?

Comment: For testing purposes, so I can see the contents of the line.

Comment: The CSV is produced by SSIS and is ANSI encoded

Comment: I would highly recommend upgrading to the highest version of PowerShell available for your OS. This may solve your issue. For some versions of Windows, you may have to "walk" through installing v3, then v4, then v5. Upgrading straight from v2 to v5 doesn't work. Also be sure to install the latest version of .Net available to your OS.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell v3 or later, you can try

```
Import-Csv filename.csv -Encoding Default
```

In PowerShell v2, you can try

```
Get-Content filename.csv | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I've tried it but get an error message stating: Import-Csv : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'encoding'.